# Cannot find draw mode

Tags: interface

I want to draw some straight lines on a mesh plane, between specific coordinates, which from what I've read seems like a job for the Line tool in Draw mode. The Blender manual says "Draw Mode is selected with the Mode menu in the 3D Viewport header", but the Mode menu in the 3D Viewport header doesn't have a "Draw Mode" entry, just "Object Mode", "Edit Mode", "Sculpt Mode", "Vertex Paint", "Weight Paint" and "Texture Paint". Has the mode moved, or is there something else I need to do first?

Answer (score 7):

In order to enter the Draw Mode you need to add a Grease Pencil Object (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) once you do that press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and you will see Draw Mode